# Crystal Report not showing correct data

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Hi I am designing a report using Crystal Report in VS 2010 C# to show students details.

I have designed the Crystal Report like below.
[image: Report design]

and my actual database table data is

[image: Table data]

but I am getting output is

[image: Output]

What will be the problem?

Comment: This is due to not enough space been allocated to display data! Right click on those field and -> `Format Field`. Format the fields according to data type and as you need to display!! Also make sure you allocate enough space for each field

Comment: @huMptyduMpty thanks for your suggestion but not getting this option. Could you please clarify it little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashok as per your question information there might not be any error in your coding but might have error in Cristal report or Application setting.

Check your both that applications and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not quite clear what the issue you have at the moment. But based on your comments there are few areas that I think can be gone wrong.

1. Check you have correct data source set up (Right click on student under Database fields and go to set data source location and check you are connected to correct database and table)
2. Also go to file and check whether you have save data with report option is selected. If it is unselect that option
3. Try go to database and do verify database
4. Reason behind you seeing values like `######` is definitely because of not enough space been allocated

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You see the "######" because the field itself is not big enough to display the data. There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Click on the field to highlight it. Then move the mouse along the frame until the cursor changes to an arrow that points left and right ( <-->). Click and hold the left mouse button and resize the field (just like you would resize a window).
2. You can right-click on the field, select Format Field, and under the common tab you can check the "Can Grow" option.

Comment: thanks @campagbolo but my problem is not ##### values my problem is I am not getting actual values from database.

Comment: @Ashok_Karale: *I am not getting actual values from database*, so how you have the picture 3 in question? where it came from??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I don't know from where are they but that are not my actual values. My actual values are in second images and this screenshot is from SQL server.